# I am attempting to create a function that shows how many consecutive days, two consecutive array inputs have deviated more than 2

Tags: c++

I am attempting to determine the number of days the stock price differed by more than $2.00 within a 2-day consecutive period. Display the results.

I cannot see the issue, it runs with no complication errors, I only receive 0.

This is the code portion of the function.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 8, 30, 40, 100};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int j = 0;
    int k = 1;
    int chg = 0;

    while (j < size && k < size)
    {
        if (j != k && arr[j] - arr[k] == 2)
        {
            chg++;
        }
        else if (j != k && arr[j] - arr[k] == -2)
        {
            chg++;
        }

        j++;
        k++;
    }
    cout << "\nThe number of days that the stock changed more than $2.00 is: " << chg << endl;
}
```

Comment: If your code compiles - it doesn't mean that it runs correctly. Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Please start changing your variable names :(

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also, you say more than two, but your code does `==`. You probably want `>=`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I am new to programming and I have a lot to learn, I will take all your advice and learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr[j] - arr[k] == -2` and `arr[j] - arr[k] == 2` can be replaced with `abs(arr[j] - arr[k]) == 2` and `j != k` is not needed since k is always +1 of j and do you see a case in your example where they differ by exactly two ? No, So you need `>=` so that becomes `abs(arr[j] - arr[k]) >= 2`

Comment: Thank you so much, I really did not think of using abs. I could get rid of the redundancy.